# How to store variable name for lazy evaluation in tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse, lazy-evaluation

if you can help me figure out the way to tidycode this piece, it'll be very nice.

Suppose I have some dataframes:

```
guys <- tribble(
  ~First,    ~Last, 
  "John",    "Jacob", 
  "Jingle",  "Heimer",
  "Schmidt", "Tara Rara Rara Rara")

cars <- tribble(
  ~Make,    ~Model, 
  "VW",     "Jetta", 
  "Nissan", "Altima", 
  "Ford",   "GT")

the_tables <- c("guys", "cars")

file_pattern <- "./%s.csv"
```

None tidyverse way:

```
for (table_name in the_tables) {
  x    <- get(table_name)
  path <- sprintf(file_pattern, table_name)
  write_csv(x = x, path = path)
}
```

Which is simple and okaaaay. 
But we have very cool tools of tidy evaluation, and there's a `for`.

Tidy approach 1:

```
tables_df <- tibble(
  x    = map(the_tables, get),
  path = sprintf(file_pattern, the_tables))

pwalk(tables_df, write_csv)
```

While it uses `pwalk` to abstract the functional components.  It has a disadvantage of storing a copy of the datasets in the intermediate table `tables_df`.

Even `%>%`ing it would have to temporarily store all these huge datasets (cars and guys) in the temporary table.

What I'd like is what I think is a promise, but can't quite figure it out.

```
table_df <- tibble(
  x    = promise(the_tables), 
  path = sprintf(file_pattern, the_tables))
```

I have tried things like `x = syms(the_tables)` to get such a promise, and also `x = quos(syms(the_tables))`;  but I'm still missing something.

Thanks.

And then of course, I'd like to pipe it all up.

```
the_tables %>% { tibble(
    x    = promise(.), 
    path = sprintf(file_pattern, .))
  } %>% 
  pwalk(write_csv)
```

Sooo beautifully.
Halp, only one piece missing.

Comment: If it's simple, understandable and works, don't change it